# "chromedriver unexpectedly exited" when importing selenium through a DAG on local airflow deployment

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, airflow

I am trying to orchestrate a ETL pipeline with Airflow running on my local machine. I am using the "standard" docker-compose.yaml file from the apache.airflow webpage (this one: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.3/docker-compose.yaml), my only alterations are mounting parts of my local file system onto docker, and using a custom image for allowing some python libraries to be installed (like selenium). This setup is working fine for some of my pipelines, but I have one involving webscraping with selenium that I cannot get to work.

I get an DAG import error:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/brand_delta/my_dags/amazon_italy_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 106, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 119, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self.path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /opt/airflow/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

The DAG imports a separate script, where the driver is initialized like this:

```
def  init_chrome_browser(chrome_driver_path, url):

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('window-size=2560,1440')

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver_path), options=options)

    browser.get(url)

    return browser
```

For some reason the chromedriver keeps "unexpectedly exiting". I have tried both installing the chromedriver on my local machine and mounting the file location to the docker-compose image, and installing chromedriver inside of the docker container of the airflow-worker, but in both cases I get this error.

I have also tried complementing the chromedriver with packages such as "libglib2.0..." inside of the worker and I do get chromedriver to start if I run it from the terminal of the worker. But still it gives me the same error when trying to run it with airflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have your chromedriver installed on all running airflow docker containers? Are you able to run your webscraping python code on worker and/or scheduler container out of airflow?

Comment: I did have the chromedriver installed on both the worker and scheduler, but I did not have google-chrome installed on the scheduler, this seems to have fixed it. At least I have new error so that's progress, thank you Michal!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Could I kindly ask you to mark my answer as accepted and upvote in that case?

Thanks!